# Instantiating prefab in a singleton not working i.e the object is not instantiated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton

I created a singleton to load level after level and instantiate a new object from an array of objects(planets array) which is loaded with prefabs through serializefield, in each of those new levels. The levels load correctly. But the problem is the object does not get instantiated. Even trying to instantiate a separate object doesn't work. When I try Debug.Log(planets[i].name), it gives the name correctly but that object doesn't get instantiated. Can someone leave help me. I need to complete my project as soon as possible. I have attached the code below.

`public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static LevelManager levelManager;

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject[] planets;

int presentLevel;
int num;
List<int> levelNumbers;
// Start is called before the first frame update

private void Awake()
{
    if (levelManager == null)
    {
        levelManager = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(levelManager);
        presentLevel = 0;
        LoadNewRound();
        Debug.Log("-1");
    }
}

public int getPresentLevelNumber()
{
    return presentLevel;
}

public void LoadNewRound()
{
    levelNumbers = new List<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        levelNumbers.Add(i);
    }
    Debug.Log("0");
    LoadNewLevel();
    
}

public void LoadNewLevel()
{
    Debug.Log("1");
    SceneManager.LoadScene((presentLevel + 1) >= 5 ? 1 : (presentLevel + 1));
    presentLevel = (presentLevel + 1) >= 5 ? 1 : (presentLevel + 1);

    Debug.Log(num);
    num = levelNumbers[Random.Range(0, levelNumbers.Count)];
    Instantiate<GameObject>(planets[num], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Debug.Log(planets[num].name);
    levelNumbers.Remove(num);
}`
```

Comment: Can it happen because loading new scene takes not one frame, but a few frames? Try instantiating your object after new scene is loaded. My guess is that you are calling 'load scene' than immediately instantiating new object, then new scene loads and replaces an old scene with instantiated object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your code

```
 public void LoadNewLevel()
    {
        Debug.Log("1");
        SceneManager.LoadScene((presentLevel + 1) >= 5 ? 1 : (presentLevel + 1));
        presentLevel = (presentLevel + 1) >= 5 ? 1 : (presentLevel + 1);

        Debug.Log(num);
        num = levelNumbers[Random.Range(0, levelNumbers.Count)];
        Instantiate<GameObject>(planets[num], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log(planets[num].name);
        levelNumbers.Remove(num);
    }
```

Instantiate(planets[num], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

This GameObject Load on previous Scene so, you have to call Instantiate(); in Next Scene

If you Load another Scene all GameObject will Destroy except DontDestroyOnLoad() GameObject

This is example for your comment

```
public void NewFunc()
{
    num = levelNumbers[Random.Range(0, levelNumbers.Count)];
    Instantiate<GameObject>(planets[num], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Debug.Log(planets[num].name);
    levelNumbers.Remove(num);
}
```

and call `LevelManager.levelManager.NewFunc();`
Awake() or Start() on  Next Scene GameObject

Comment: can you help me with how do I approach this problem? How can I instantiate the gameobject after I load into a new scene?